# Fully Importing A Saved Colour Palette In Illustrator?

Tags: color, adobe-illustrator, mac

Is there any way to fully import a saved colour palette into Illustrator? I once saved a colour palette from one project and wanted to import the colours for use in another project, but I found that the imported colour palette was separate from the second project.

Comment: For which platform? The answer is going to be different on each.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you've saved the palette out to a known location and now want to merge it into the document's palette?

Comment: Are you wanting to automatically import your custom color swatch into every new document, or manually import into one document?

Comment: @Philip I'm on Mac.

Comment: @Jaips Manually import into one document. Basically, I want the new colour swatches that I've saved into the colour swatch file acting as a native colour swatch like before in the previous document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Mac OS X, Illustrator maintains these types of files in a couple different locations:

- `~/Users/philipr/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Illustrator CS4/en_US/Swatches/`
- `~/Applications/Adobe Illustrator CS4/Presets.localized/en_US/Swatches/`

There are all sorts of items you have pre-loaded into Adobe apps from within those folders.

I don't work in Windows, but I would imagine the locations would be the equivalnts of the user settings and the application presets folders.